# Precommit hook script to create .env.example file

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, configuration, secret-key

NodeJs Project:
I have a `.env` file at the root of my project where I store all my secrets/configs like so

```
# -- .env -- #
DB_HOSTNAME=realhostname.of.the.server.com
DB_USERNAME=realuser
DB_PASSWORD=password1234
```

For obvious reasons, this `.env` is in my `.gitignore` so doesn't get committed to Git.

To collaborate with my peers, I commit an example dotenv file, by referencing which they can create their own `.env` manually on their locals. The example hand-written dotenv file looks like this

```
# -- .env.example -- create a copy of this file with the filename .env and fill in the values #
DB_HOSTNAME=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Problem: Everytime I add a new entry to the `.env` file I have to manually add that same entry to the `.env.example` file. If I forget to add before committing, I run the danger of loosing whatever friends I have left.

**Possible Solution:** Can this process be automated? For example: a Bash script which runs in the pre-commit hook and creates an `.env.example` file by removing all the values, but keeping all the keys from `.env` file ?

Comment: You could automate that, yes. StackOverflow is more suited to "I wrote this as my solution and it has problem X, as shown here, so how do I fix that? Background, goal is automating..." Personally I'd instead use a pre-commit hook that compares the displayed settings in the example file to the actual settings in any actual file and inhibits the commit if not, so that "problem X" isn't "but adding in the pre-commit hook doesn't always work".

Answer (score 1):

I am using `dotenv` in my rails project. The library can be found here:

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

In the documentation there is reference to using the command line executable to create a template from your `.env` file like so:

`dotenv -t .env`

The above will take the contents of your current environment file and create an updated template, stripping all of the values and only leaving the keys. Everytime I modify my environment file I run this command to ensure the template is always up to date and then commit the template to the repository.

I haven't done it yet, but the next step would be to create a git hook to run this command so the template is always up to date.

Hope this helps?